# Why Travis cannot run my tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I used Xcode 9.0 and iPhone 7 in my development.
In my `.travis.yml` I added:

```
language: swift
osx_image: xcode9
script:
- xcodebuild clean test -project BullsEye.xcodeproj -scheme BullsEye
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=11" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" 
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -quiet
```

but when I run it in travis I get this:

```
The command "xcodebuild clean test -project BullsEye.xcodeproj -scheme BullsEye 
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=11" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" 
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -quiet" exited with 70.
```

or with `66`.

I made my scheme `Shared` in Xcode.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

In logs I'm also getting:

```
Ineligible destinations for the "BullsEye" scheme:
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
```

and

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:11, name:iPhone 7 }
The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
```

Comment: can you share a link to the full log on travis-ci.org? If it's private, can you copy/paste the log on https://gist.github.com? Thanks!

Comment: @DominicJodoin https://travis-ci.org/orkhanalizade/BullsEye it's here

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [your latest build log](https://travis-ci.org/orkhanalizade/BullsEye/jobs/274173992), the following error message

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:11, name:iPhone 7 }
```

seems to indicate that you aren't using a valid `-destination` value.

Indeed, I believe that `11` isn't an accepted value for `OS`. Can you try with `11.0` instead? i.e. `-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=11.0"`

I've also submitted a PR [here](https://github.com/orkhanalizade/BullsEye/pull/1).